# Ajax Login issue

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, web

PHP connector

```
    // Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect($host, $username, $password)or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

/* escape entered values to prevent sql nastyness */
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

if(!empty($username) && !empty($password)){ 

    /* we query through our database to search for a username that has been entered */
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE UserLogin = '$username' AND UserPass='$password'");

    if(mysql_num_rows($query) == 1){
        /* if there is a match with the database, we select the username and password from the database corresponding to the entered username */
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
            $db_username = $row['username'];
            $db_password = $row['password'];
        }
        /* we compare the entered username and password with the ones we just selected from the database */
        if($username == $db_username && $password == $db_password){
            /* If the entered username and password are correct, return 1 */
            echo '1';
        }
    } else {
        /* If the entered username or password do not match, return 2 */
        echo 'Username or Password are wrong';
    }
} else {
    /* If both fields are empty, return 3 */
    echo 'Username and Password are empty';
}
```

Javascript

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#login_form').submit(function() {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'php/check_login_online.php',
            data: {
                username: $("#username").val(),
                password: $("#password").val()
            },
            success: function(data)
            {
                if (data === '1') {
                    window.location.replace('php/search.php');
                }
                else {
                    alert(data);
                }
            }
        });

    });

});
```

HTML

```
    <div class="container">

    <div class="form-bg">
        <form id='login_form'>
            <h2>test Login</h2>

            <p><input name="username" placeholder="Username" type="text" id="username"></p>
            <p><input name="password" placeholder="Password" type="password" id="password" ></p>

            <label class='error' id='error' style='display: none; font-size: 12px;'></label>

            <button type="submit" name="Submit" class="submit" value="Login"></button>
        </form>
    </div>


    <!-- <p class="forgot">Forgot your password? <a href="">Click here to reset it.</a></p> -->


</div>

<!-- JS  -->
<script src="js/ajax-login.js"></script>
```

I cut down on the extra code but when i hit login button, the url changes but stays on the login page with the username and password but there is no validation. Thank you for the help.

Comment: What exactly goes wrong?

Comment: **Do not store passwords in plain text**.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection. Consider using `mysqli_*` or `PDO` with prepared statements instead.

Comment: I was going to add in bcrpyt but i wanted to get this working first.

Comment: 1. no plain text pwds; 2. no prehistoric `mysql_*` funcs; 3. what's the point of making an ajax login and then messing with `window.location`? Do a plain old sync call just in case!

Comment: You should look into using PDO or MySQLi with prepared statements, mysql_ functions have been deprecated.

Comment: PS Some of your logic seems unnecessary, for example when checking the database if something specifically exists (username and password) (I assume the username is unique) then there is no need to check if they are equal.

Comment: I am looking at PDO, I will implement it.

Comment: Try to use `window.location` instead of `window.location.replace`, however I haven't understood your problem

Comment: Why are you using Javascript, can't you just set the form action to the login page and check for the submit php side? Then can redirect as necessary. Also js can be disabled. And as stated don't use plain text passwords, look into password hashing with a salt.

Comment: Also you should add `return !1;` in your login js function or `onclick='javascript:return !1;` in your button tag

Comment: Also keep in mind that you could have some problems with the button tag to submit forms, use the input equivalent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add `return false` at the end of jQuery submit. This will prevent the form's default action.

This is necessary in order to make ajax login work.

Updated JavaScript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#login_form').submit(function() {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'php/check_login_online.php',
        data: {
            username: $("#username").val(),
            password: $("#password").val()
        },
        success: function(data) {
            if (data === '1') {
                window.location.replace('php/search.php');
            } else {
                alert(data);
            }
        }
    });

    return false;
});

});
```

Answer (score 1):

looking into the problem I can suggest few things:

1. Use form action to call php and do validations.
2. redirect to next page from php itself